# How can I say a word or any expression "a very small dust"?

Tags: expressions

In some news, I see the words "fine dust", but it sounds strange.

Is it a common phrase?

ex) Fine dust is in the air.

Comment: "Specks" is what you're looking for.

Comment: "Powder" is another possible term, but there's no clear rule as to whether "dust" or "powder" refers to a finer material.

Comment: In technical parlance, "particulates".

Answer (score 3):

- "Fine dust particles" is a common phrase
- If just one dust, "a speck of dust" is a common phrase

Answer (score 0):

nanoparticles
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanoparticle
are perhaps the finest non-molecular lumps.